# Swiping on a jqxgrid does not work on my mobile phone

Tags: mobile, jqxgrid

I have a page containing a jqxgrid from JQWidgets, which is bigger than the screen size of my mobile phone. If I want to swipe the grid to the left to see the content on the right part I have to swipe on an area outside of the grid.

Now if it happens that the grid covers the whole screen and I do not see any area outside of it I cannot swipe at all any more to see any other part of the grid/page

I tried selectionmode: 'none', enablehover: false, but it did not make any difference for the swiping. 
I just installed the latest version 8.3.2 of the 12 jqxgrid files. -> Same
What I just discovered: If I start swiping the screen by touching an area outside of the grid and then while the screen is still moving I quickly place my finger on top of the grid and continue swiping it works. However as soon as the screen stops moving I cannot start moving it any more by swiping on the grid

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the version of the JQWidgets. I had version 4.1.2 installed. I replaced it with version 8.3.2 (the whole package had to be replaced not just the jqxgrid files) and now it works fine.